# OpenGL rotation too sensitive

Tags: opengl, haskell, matrix, linear-algebra

I recently switched from using the deprecated `gl_*Matrix` to handling matrices on my own. Everything seems to be working fine, except that rotation is about 80 times what it should be. I can switch to using opengl's matrices without changing any other code, and rotation is fine. The complete source is on [Github](https://github.com/fiendfan1/Haskell-OpenGL/blob/master/Modern/Engine/Matrix/Matrix.hs). The most relevant function is here:

```
calculateMatricesFromPlayer :: GameObject a -> WorldMatrices
calculateMatricesFromPlayer p@(Player{}) =
    let Vec3 px py pz = playerPosition p
        Vec3 rx ry _ = playerRotation p

        -- Create projection matrix
        projMat = gperspectiveMatrix 45 (800/600) 0.1 100

        -- Create view matrix
        rotatedMatX = grotationMatrix rx [-1, 0, 0]
        rotatedMatXY = rotatedMatX * grotationMatrix ry [0, -1, 0]
        translatedMat = gtranslationMatrix [-px, -py, -pz]
        viewMat = rotatedMatXY * translatedMat

        -- Model matrix is identity by default
        modelMat = gidentityMatrix
    in WorldMatrices modelMat viewMat projMat
```

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

Comment: could this be a degree to radians issue

Answer (score 8):

Since there are `360` degrees and `2*pi` radians in a circle, with `pi` being approximately 3, it seems very likely that being out by a factor of approximately 80 is you using degrees as input to `sin`, `cos` or `tan` functions which are taking input as radians, since `360/(2*pi)` is approximately 80.